# How to repeat group header per sub group in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2016

Is there any way to repeat the group header of the report for each sub group like below in SSRS?
[image]

I keep looking on google but it only gives me a solution on how to repeat the group header on each page but that's not what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the static row group that corresponds to your subgroup. In the rows group area, click the dropdown arrow on the left and select '**Advanced Mode**'.
Click through the rows under Row Groups until you find the static group that highlights your subtitle. Open the Properties of that group (F4), and set **KeepWithGroup** to **After** and **RepeatOnNewPage** to **True**.